# How to create Custom fields with Sales-force Rest Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, salesforce, salesforce-chatter, databasedotcom-gem

I am having a requirement to create contacts using Salesforce-Bulk-API in salesforce account. My question is can we also create custom fields for Contact object in salesforce using bulk API?

```
    salesforce =  SalesforceBulkApi::Api.new(@client)
    records_to_insert = Array.new
    socialcrm_list.socialcrm_list_records.each do |record|
    new_record = {"FirstName" => record.first_name, "LastName" => record.last_name, "Email" => record.email1, "Phone" => record.phone1, "HomePhone" => record.phone3, "MobilePhone" => record.phone2, "MailingStreet" => record.address1, "MailingCity" => record.city,"MailingState" => record.state, "MailingCountry" => record.country, "MailingPostalCode" => record.zip, "CustomField" => record.job}
    records_to_insert.push(new_record)
```

I have tried passing `CustomField` as an attribute in the hash, but it is not working. Is there any way we can pass extra attributes in Hash without adding them exclusively from Salesforce developer Account

Attached a reference image of sales-force custom attribute form over [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUfjS.png)